# Is there a solution for this case?

Tags: c++, windows

This is a `Windows Desktop Application` project created by `Visual Studio`.
I have a `Dialog` resource created from the `Resource View` that has a `Static Text`.
I'm using this dialog in order to show errors to the user:

```
DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_MY_MESSAGE_BOX), hWnd, MyMessageBoxProc);
```

The reason I'm using a `DialogBox` is that I need it to stop the code execution, because the next line of code will close the application I mean the user should be aware of the error message before application exits. I know a way to change the `Static Text`:

```
HWND myMessageBox = CreateDialog(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_MY_MESSAGE_BOX), nullptr, MyMessageBoxProc);
HWND staticText = GetDlgItem(myMessageBox, IDC_STATIC);
SetWindowText(staticText, L"Text changed.");
```

But that approach doesn't stop code execution.
Since it's a `Windows Desktop Application` project I cannot create `MFC` classes and try the following approach:

```
// Find the Static Text.
// If called from within MyMessageBox class.
CWnd *staticText = GetDlgItem(IDC_STATIC);
staticText->SetWindowText("Text changed.");

// If called from elsewhere.
MyMessageBox myMessageBox;
CWnd *staticText = myMessageBox.GetDlgItem(IDC_STATIC);
staticText->SetWindowText("Text changed.");
```

So what would be a workaround in order to change the `Static Text` using a `DialogBox` without the need of `MFC` classes or even another approach that allows me to change the `Static Text` and still stop code execution like a `DialogBox`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the text in your window procedure (`MyMessageBoxProc`) by handling WM_INITDIALOG message.  If you wish to supply the text to the dialog, then create it using `DialogBoxParam` instead, which is then accessible via the `lParam` parameter.

*e.g.*

```
INT_PTR MyMessageBoxProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (message == WM_INITDIALOG) {
        HWND hCtrl = GetDlgItem(hWnd, IDC_STATIC);
        SetWindowText(hCtrl, reinterpret_cast<LPCTSTR>(lParam));
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

The creation would be something like:

```
LPCTSTR text = _T("Text changed.");
DialogBoxParam(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_MY_MESSAGE_BOX), hWnd, MyMessageBoxProc,
    reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(text));
```

Note that there is a standard message box that ships with windows, which you may want to use instead of writing your own.  That's available via the function [MessageBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-messagebox)